# Firebase Java SDK offline

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to use Firebase java SDK (To Desktop applications) offline? Is possible? I need this function to use software desktop offline and sincronization with Android using Firebase.

Comment: firebase is a cloud-based db. taking it "offline" is a contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Firebase Java SDK will handle intermittent connectivity loss. It will simply keep the data it's already received in memory and will queue any local modifications in memory until it has a connection to the server again.

This data will be lost when the user restarts of the application. There is an [option to persist the data to disk](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-05-29-announcing-mobile-offline-support.html), but that is only available for [iOS](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/offline-capabilities.html#section-enabling-offline-support) and [Android](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/offline-capabilities.html#section-enabling-offline-support).

Comment: This is problem for me: "that is only available for iOS and Android". I need persist data on Java SE (Softwares Desktop). Thanks for the answer.